# Draw image constrain aspects

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an imageview, the image within this imageview is for you to choose from the photoroll. I also have a button, when you click this button, there's an image added to a view with the addSubview code. This piece of image is draggable, resizeable and rotatable.

One problem, when I finish the image I use the method drawInRect. This draws all the layers onto eachother and creates an image. However the layers are on the wrong place and are the wrong size. It's also never rotated. I don't know how to fix this, the piece of code is beneath this text. Is it possible to keep the original image size and still have the layers drawn on the same place I drag them onto the imageview, if not how do I create a new size for this and have the result I want. And how do I draw the image rotated.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView2.image.size);    
// Draw image1
[imageView2.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView2.image.size.width, imageView2.image.size.height)];    
// Draw image2
for(UIImageView *viewsSub in [self.imageViewer subviews])
{            
    [viewsSub.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(viewsSub.frame.origin.x, viewsSub.frame.origin.y, viewsSub.frame.size.width, viewsSub.frame.size.height)];
}    
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
pld.imageChosen2 = resultingImage;    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like taking a "screenshot" of your actual imageview (with subviews included), don't you?

I used this piece of code to do something similar, but don't know if would work for you.

```
     - (UIImage *)screenshot {
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen screenScale];

        if(scale > 1.5) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, scale);
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        }
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenshot; 
}
```

You should add this method inside your imageview (the one that contains all the subviews you're adding).